# Selenium Java Chrome: Stale exception

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Here is a code fragment:

```
    System.setProperty(Constants.WEBDRIVER_CHROME_DRIVER_PROP, Constants.WEBDRIVER_CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);

    m_chromeWebdriver = new ChromeDriver();
    m_chromeWebdriver.get("mysite.org");

    WebElement arrowElement = m_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(_ARROW_NEXT_DAY));
    arrowElement.click();

    WebElement elmMainTable = m_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.className("table-main"));

    List<WebElement> allRows = elmMainTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

    for (WebElement row : allRows) {
        
        List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for (WebElement cell : cells) {
            System.out.println(cell.getText());
        }
    }
    m_chromeWebdriver.quit();
```

At the last line I get an

> "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page
> document"

exception.

Why and how can I solve that?
I use Chromdriver 2.2.9.

Comment: you are iterating the list element through the loop. right  ?

Comment: `elmNextDayArrow.click();` what does this line do?

Comment: @NarendraRajput I'd like to...

Comment: Please fix you code and provide an [mcve] so we can help you.

Comment: @kushal. - clicks the element... This is less important... It works. The problem is in the last line.

Comment: @dushkin: clicks the element and then what happens?

Comment: @kushal. I don't know to explain precisely what happens, but I guess that new data is loaded from the DB to the table.

Comment: @SiKing I extended the example. The exception is thrown for all the lines starting from List<WebElement> allRows = elmMainTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

Comment: @dushkin what do you mean all the line starting with `List<WebElement> allRows = elmMainTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));` ?

Comment: @kushal. I mean that the execution of each code line throws this exception. And that begins with the line you mentioned

Comment: try adding 10 secs wait after arrowElement.click();

Comment: @kushal. It did seem to help! Even with 5 seconds waiting. But still, isn't there any more dedicated solution?

Comment: Although your code looks fine, but I'm not sure what it arrowelement.clik does, can you share with me elmMainTable.getText() result?

Comment: @kushal. The arrow is simply an image I click. The getText() retrieves table cell text

Comment: okay try: `List<WebElement> allRows = elmMainTable.findElements(By.cssSelector(".table-main tr"));`

Comment: @kushal. That's nice. It really saved me a sleep time before the original line. And now I have the exception on : List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); What shoud I do here, and what is the general idea of the solution?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but try changing `List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));` to  `List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.cssSelector("td"));` and share the result of `System.out.println(cells.size());`

Comment: @kushal. Doesn't help... :(

Comment: what is tje output of System.out.println(cells.size());?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143593/discussion-between-dushkin-and-kushal).

Answer (score 0):

Well, as this is probably not the perfect solution - at least it worked for me...

I put all the relevant code into a method like this:

```
private static void handleTable() {

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

    try {
        WebElement elmMainTable = m_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.className("table-main"));

        List<WebElement> allRows = elmMainTable.findElements(By.cssSelector(".table-main tr"));

        for (WebElement row : allRows) {

            List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

            for (WebElement cell : cells) {

                System.out.print(cell.getText() + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {

        //e.printStackTrace();

        handleTable();
    }

    return;
}
```

}

And it worked! You can change the value 5 to which ever you'd like of course.

Answer (score -1):

I learned the main reason for Selenium stale exception is element changed in DOM. In case, the stale exception are caused by those web elements you are not handling, you can try below try-catch and continue method in JAVA.

```
//get webelement list of button on the OU tab
List<WebElement> ouList = 
Logon.wDriver.findElements(By.tagName(PagePropertise.tagButton)); 
// it should be 6
System.out.println("List Size is: "+ouList.size()); 

for (int i=0; i<ouList.size(); i++ ) {
   //get each button element to verify with input Org name
    WebElement ouName= ouList.get(i); 
    String ouLabel = null;
    try {
        ouLabel = ouName.getText();
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        //handle in exception catch, just skip invalid element and continue for to handle rest of loop
        System.out.println("WebElement "+i+" = text "+ ouLabel);
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println("WebElement "+i+" = text "+ ouLabel);

    //webelement processing
    ...
    //for some reason some of webelements in the OUlist were changed for above processing code.
}
```